my pc has become slow, it just gotten slower on its own
These are my computer's specs:

Intel core i5 3570
GT 710 DDR3
8GB ram

It may not be powerful by modern standards, but it can play some games , like Minecraft, kinda good. My pc can run it over 100fps and can run only one shader in like 50 to 70fps. Even if shadowplay records screen, it does not drop that much, it runs at like 56fps something if that shader is enabled, well it used to run like that.
Recently, my pc has become really slow, before it had i3 2100 so I upgraded it to i5 3570 for better performance, but no difference. It can't even run games which are 20+ years old like Metro 2033, Call of Duty Ghosts, etc. I have seen benchmark videos for some games that gt 710 can easily run it, but it doesn't. It used to run GTA 4 at 50 to 60 fps but now it runs at 20fps even though every benchmark videos showed that it can run at 60fps constant, it's supposed to run on that fps or a bit lower but is doesn't, I even overclocked it, it had big difference back then but not anymore.
When I upgraded my processor to i5 3570, it did had some difference, Euro Truck Simulator 2's fps doubled after i upgraded it, 24 fps on i3 2100, 42 constant fps on i5 3570, but now it got back to that same fps.
Somehow, Battlefield 4 runs better than Metro 2033(2010), I am talking about the original Metro 2033, not Redux. Metro 2033 gives 21fps where bf4 gives 35fps, somehow
I don't what is going on with my pc, how performance is getting slower and slower.
My pc does have a 4 year old power supply, it is possible that old power supply is reducing performance?
I did changed my monitor from 768p one to 1080p one, i don't think higher resolution monitor is reducing that much, I started to notice that performance drop issue even when I still had 768p monitor.
Please tell me what is the problem

You've looked at the hardware quite a bit: Have you looked at the software? Have you done a clean reinstall of Windows? Have you looked at the running processes to see what is using the computer's resources? Also, please note that this is a professional site, so it is recommended to keep your language professional as well.

Are those specs on the new CPU or the old? I have edited your post a bit, but in order to clarify it you must do more editing. For those games that you have performance details on the old CPU, CLEARLY note which CPU the performance details are regarding. Maybe use some formatting to help indicate which performance numbers go with which generation of your computer. But also, performance degradation can be strongly related to software, so we need information about the software state of your computer, and you need to consider that in your own diagnostic efforts.

The question about the PSU is easy to answer. Nope, your 4 year old PSU cannot be the source of performance degradation. Dont underestimate the performance difference between 768p and 1080p. Try reverting your graphics back to 768p resolutions and check the framerate again.
